# Linux server cache clearing

Tags: linux, memory-usage

I tried to search but wasn't able to find clear answer.

My VPS memory usage increase from 10% to almost 90% in day.

Output of free -m

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3869       3640        229          8         50       3424
-/+ buffers/cache:        165       3704
Swap:            0          0          0
```

I found that I can flush cached memory via command

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3869        398       3471          8          2        224
-/+ buffers/cache:        170       3699
Swap:            0          0          0
```

I also find comments about that using `drop_caches` decrease server performance.

My question is that should I clear memory cache via force. If not when cached memory is freed?

Comment: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: On a mostly idle server you may not notice the slight slowdown over the next minutes or hours while everything is re-cached but if the server is busy then it can have an extreme and immediately noticeable negative effect. Dropping caches is useful for benchmarking, but should be avoided in normal operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, don't drop caches. Linux will free them as soon as it has better use for it (e.g. a process requires it).